# How to use awk-it in Emacs?

Tags: awk, emacs

I'm a pretty new Emacs user and I want to call *awk* from *Emacs*. After googling around I found **awk-it** at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AWK_It. However I still can't understand how to use it after I read it's documentation. When I try to select some text and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> **awk-it**, I got the following error in minibuffer:

> Symbol's value as variable is void; kbd

Can anyone help to write an example to demonstrate how to use it?